# Windows 8: BFSVC Error: Could not open the BCD template store. Status = [c000000f]

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation, bootloader, bcd

I have installed a new hard disk drive on my Acer Aspire 771. I made a USB recovery stick as well as recovery cd of the Windows 8 64 bit running on the former HD (which got corrupted, so no cloning possible).

After two days of struggling, I managed to get the recovery going, but it aborted at about 80 % of loading. As before, the system is not booting, and only the recovery disk helps me to get the command promt (all other repair options fail).

I tried to recreate the BCD, doing something like:

```
select vol 2 --> EFI
assign --> resulted in F: drive
select vol 3 --> Windows8_OS drive (471 GB)
assign --> resulted in G: drive
exit
cd /d F:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
bootrec /fixboot
ren BCD BCD.bak
bcdboot G:\Windows /l en-us /s f: /f ALL
```

to no avail, resulting in the mentioned error message

I also tried:

```
BOOTREC /FIXMBR
BOOTREC /FIXBOOT 
BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD
```

without success.

I'm getting into slight dispair...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The error could be caused by running the command without administrator privileges. I found that running the command with administrator privileges fixed this error (at least for me).

Comment: Worked for me and solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly states that "BCD Template" is not present (or cannot be read).

BCD Template is in `\Windows\System32\Config` folder.

`bcdboot` command uses it for recreating BCD on system partition.

The possible solution is to obtain a Windows 8/64-bit installation DVD or ISO image and do a offline repair using `SFC` command (use DVD or mounted ISO as source for all repair operations like `bcdboot` for example).

`SFC` will repair/recreate all Windows system files.

Comment: does it need special syntax or do you just boot from installation/repair CD, go to the repair console and then SFC somehow know on which Windows installation to run on?

Comment: sfc has options and parameters .. and help as every Windows utility ;) Surprisingly sfc only displays help ;)

Comment: to reply to myself, the offline (having booted from installation/repair disk) syntax is usually  SFC /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=C:\ /OFFWINDIR=D:\WINDOWS if you use UEFI (the system boots from other partition than the one Windows is), but it might also be E:\WINDOWS for the windows directory (have to check each disk to find it, since booting from installation CD results in other drive letters than usual). In my case this still didn't help, SFC was failing for other reasons to work

Comment: Example syntax and explanation of parameters - https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html

Comment: This ends with `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.` but i still cant boot. Back to `0x000000f`

Comment: Just copy "BCD template", then again repair steps. No "BCD template" = NO FIX with MS tools.

Comment: If you fixed your booting it would be nice to give feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this error too. I got it working by booting for an USB drive created with [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus). A Windows DVD or another bootable medium would work too. Maybe the path changes in that case.

I verified if the BCD-Template file exists from the command prompt (which in my case didn't) by issuing:

```
dir %WINDIR%\System32\Config\BCD*
```

Then I copied the BCD-template file from the Rufus disk (X:) by issuing:

```
xcopy X:\windows\System32\Config\BCD-Template %WINDIR%\System32\Config\BCD-Template
```

Then executed again the bcdboot-command. In my case this was:

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s K: /f UEFI
```

The command then worked fine.
Change those params to match your case.

- **C:\Windows** – is the path to the directory with Windows 10 installed;
- **/f <ALL/BIOS/UEFI>** – means that you want to copy the Windows Boot Environment files, including those for UEFI and BIOS computers (potential ability to boot in UEFI and BIOS systems). To copy only the EFI bootloader, use the /f UEFI command
- **/l en-us** — is a type of the system locale. By default, en-us – English (USA) is used;
- **/c** – this is a new BCDBoot option in Windows 10 that allows you to overwrite existing boot records (including debugsettings). Use this option to ignore old boot settings and create a clean BCD configuration;
- **/v** – used to enable BCDBoot verbose output.

Source: [woshub.com](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-uefi-bootloader-in-windows-8/)

The command then worked fine.